# django access related user model value in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model looking like this.

```
class ProjectMembership(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='project_membership_member_set')
```

Edit: In a template I want now to access the last_name of the User model. I thought it should work like the following line, but it does not.

```
{{ project_membership.member.last_name }}
```

No error is provided. Just the value is missing. I just want to print out the first and last name of the User object referenced in the variable member. Interestingly

```
{{ project_membership.member }}
```

does work. This prints out the “human-readable” representation of the User object.

Comment: There's not enough context for us to provide a helpful answer here.  Are you getting an error?  What does your view look like?

Comment: You should be able to user the first style (`{{ project_membership.member.last_name }}`) - I use that style all over my templates with no problem. Something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `project_membership.member` gives you the user, then `project_membership.member.last_name` *should* give you that user's `last_name`.

Are you absolutely sure that the user you're testing for has `last_name` set? Do you get any output on `project_membership.member.username`? If you try to access `project_membership.member.last_name` in your view or through the shell, do you get an error or an empty unicode string?

Comment: OMG. The value is obviously not set in the db. I should not go out and try to code the next day .. haha.. It works now with project_membership.member.last_name.